# Keywords or Names for this Part

Tags: pvc, hardware, fitting

I am trying to embed a load-bearing anchor in a 1-inch foam sheet. The most natural solution would be some kind of threaded plastic pair that fits together, with one end being able to have a rope attached. Something like this:

[image: drawing]

I don't know what terms to search for, however. I've found promising items searching for "plastic flanges" or "bulkhead fittings" but they either have much too small a flange (e.g. half inch wider than threads), or are only available in bulk. Threads are not required (I'm willing to use pvc cement) but ideally, it'd also be UV-resistant, as this is intended for outdoor use. Is there a more accurate name I could be searching for instead?

In case it's relevant, my specific plan is to add an additional three attachment points to a foam raft such as the following:

[image: photo]

Comment: perhaps some kind of a `gromet` would work

Comment: That’s what I was thinking. Most likely stainless steel grommet

Comment: My kids have a party island that has 3 large grommets for towing, this thing is huge but you may be able to find them as a replacement part I don’t know the brand but they got it at Costco and it is like 12’ x 18’ , they may have been for anchorage but we use them to take it to the middle of the lake (no kids riding ).

Comment: @EdBeal that's actually exactly what I'm trying to add these to. Ours only has one mount. They're not cheap either, around $200.

Comment: Yes I asked the kids because there was a book of replacement parts and patches that came with it but they can’t find it but possibly they have it on line.

Comment: [Found](https://aqualilypad.com/store/accessories/aqua-lily-pad-tether-kit.html) the part but they want $50 for it!